# Solving Double Summation

Tags: summation

I came across the following summation but I don't know how to solve it:
$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n (j + 1)$
I know how to do double summations, but I never saw double summations that are linked like this before though.

Comment: Forget the summand $j+1$ for a second. Put $n=5$ and draw a $5\times 5$ grid of dots. Label the rows $i$ and the columns $j$ and circle the ones that correspond to values being summed. This should give you a better idea of how to compute the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any fixed $i$ we have
$$\sum_{j=i}^{n}(j+1)=\frac{(n-i+1)(n+i+2)}{2}.$$
Thus, the sum becomes
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(n-i+1)(n-i+2)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n^2+3n-i^2-i+2).$$
Evaluating the sum term by term then gives
$$\frac{1}{2}(n^3+3n^2-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+2n).$$
Simplifying, we get
$$\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}.$$
Feel free to ask if you aren't sure about any of the above steps.

Answer (score 2):

One way I haven't seen in the answers is to reverse the order of the summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n j+1 = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^j j+1 = \sum_{j=1}^n j^2 + j $$

which we can use the usual formulas on

$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

This ends up being easier because the summand does not depend on $i$ at all, so it's the equivalent of "integrating" a constant.

Answer (score 1):

$\Sigma_{i=1}^n\Sigma_{j=i}^n(j+1)=(\Sigma_{j=1}^n(j+1)+\Sigma_{j=2}^n(j+1)+\cdots\Sigma_{j=n}^n(j+1))$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: rewrite the double summation.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n(j+1)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n(j+1)-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}(j+1)\right)$$

Comment: Awesome, Thank you, double summations confuse me a lot and this hint really helped me understand the problem!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n(j+1)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n(j+1)-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}(j+1)\right)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n (j + 1) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n.(n+1)}{2} + n - \frac{i(i-1)}{2} -i+1 = \frac{n.(n+1).(n+2)}{3}$$
Now for any general $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n f(i,j)$,

- first sum over j taking i as constant in $f(i,j)$ without paying any heed to the summation over i
- once you are done with summation over j, next sum over i as you do normally for a single summation
  P.S. - It's easier to sum when summation starts with 1. So always try to convert in that form.